# yaws not building on CentOS after erlang build OK

Tags: centos, yaws, erl

**Problem:**

yaws configure is failing after autoconf with unable to find erl

**Question:**

Why this error is showing, because erl can be found from a bash shell from anywhere

which erl  --> /usr/local/bin/erl

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider running the configure script via `sh -x configure` to see the detailed output showing exactly what the `configure` script is doing. Be warned that there'll potentially be a lot of output to sift through. Feel free to email the [Yaws mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/erlyaws-list) if you need help deciphering it.